# How do I solve the first order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{(1+ky-y/x)}{(1-y^2)}$$

$$y(0) = 0$$

I have tried using change of variables such as $x=y^2z$, or $x=yz$, however, I am still not able to separate the equation. Any thoughts on whether i should consider a different change of variable?

Comment: What is the range of values for parameter $k$ ? Have you attempted $k=0$ ?

Comment: Even for $k=0$ nor WA nor maple give a solution, I would be very pessimistic...

Comment: @zwim If WA and Maple could not find the solutions, then it is very likely that the equation has no elementary solutions. In that case, there is no substitution you can do that can help you.

Comment: You cannot have the initial condition at $x=0$ where the ODE is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

This equation is not integrable for any real $k$.
Consider the planar system equivalent:
$$\begin{cases}x'&=&x(1-y^2)\\
y'&=&x+kxy-y\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
A solution to the original ODE is equivalent to a first integral for the system. By the theorem 5.2 in Goriely's **"Integrability and nonintegrability of dynamical systems"**, this system has a first integral around any equilibrium point only if the linear eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are in "resonance", that is: for each equilibrium $p_j$, the eigenvalues $a_j$ and $b_j$ of the Jacobian matrix in $p_j$ must satisfy: $$ma_j+nb_j=0,$$
for $m$ and $n$ positive integers.

This system has equilibrium points: $p_1=(0,0)$, $p_2=(\frac{1}{k+1},1)$ and $p_3=(\frac{1}{k-1},-1)$. If you take the Jacobian in $p_2$, the eigenvalues are
$$a_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-8k^2-16k-7}}{2(k+1)}$$ and $$b_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{-8k^2-16k-7}}{2(k+1)}.$$
So we need $m$ and $n$ that
$$m\frac{-1+\sqrt{-8k^2-16k-7}}{2(k+1)} +n\frac{-1-\sqrt{-8k^2-16k-7}}{2(k+1)}=0.$$
After some manipulations we get: $$8k^2+16k+7+(\frac{m+n}{m-n})^2=0,$$
wich has no real solutions.

[image]

*Fig. 1: The vector field induced by (1) in the case $k=2$ displaying equilibrium points $(1/3,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ (figure included by JeanMarie).*

Here is the Matlab program that has been used to create the plot:

> ```
> axis([-2,2,-2,2]);hold on;
> [x,y]=meshgrid(-2:0.1:2);
> k=2;
> u=x.*(1-y.^2);v=x+k*x.*y-y;
> n=sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);
> u=u./n;v=v./n;
> quiver(x,y,u,v,1);
> ```

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include a plot ot the vector field associated with the differential system.

Comment: 1) Thank you for this excellent solution; I have learned concepts I wasn't aware of. 2) A little remark about your last sentence: instead of "real solutions", you should say "which has no **all positive integer** solutions", because equation  $8(k+1)^2-1+((m+n)/(m-n))^2=0$ possesses this integer solution $k=-1,m=1,n=0$.

Comment: A question: is this an Hamiltonian system ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, note that $m$ and $n$ must be positive integers, so the last equation is about $k$. Also $k$ itself need not to be integer, should just produce ressonace. About the system being Hamiltonian, note that the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ has eigenvalues with positive real part for all $k$, so the system is "anti-dissipative" around the origin and cannot be conservative.